Asking "what time is it in Japan？", what particle?
First let me say that I know that there are similar threads, this in particular. There are some things I still want to make clear. So, it appears that the most natural way to ask the question in the title would be

1. 日本は何時ですか。

I understand why in such a question one would want 日本 to be the topic, still I'm struggling to understand whether the usage of another particle is ungrammatical or just unnatural/forced. If I said

2. 日本で何時ですか。

would it just be wrong?
Then what about making it both topic and location as in

3. 日本では何時ですか。

Of course the same questions hold for に, although the question linked about seems to suggest you can't, but I want to be sure whether it just sounds stiff or plainly wrong.
I think my main problem with this is that I read such a sentence as if the actual subject were being omitted:

(今、時間は) ６時です。

so that's why I don't understand whether it's wrong. In this light, my sentences would be like

4. 今、時間は日本で６時です。

So that the copula refers to 時間, and the usual structure of the copula is respected.
I hope I could explain my doubts clearly, that is whether my sentences are stiff or just wrong. I would appreciate if you commented my sentences 2, 3, 4, and compare it to 1. Thank you for your attention.

で as a location marker works with an action or an event, but it's not a commonly used particle when expressing the current time. If used, it somehow implies that the location is being contrasted or explicitly emphasized.


日本は何時ですか。


This is the most natural way to ask. で (or に) is not necessary to express time.


日本で何時ですか。


This is grammatically correct but sounds like the 日本で part is unnecessarily emphasized. This might be appropriate if you had just asked about the time in Japan but someone told you the time in Spain instead.


日本では何時ですか。


This sounds more neutral than Sentence 2, but still, you would typically hear this only after discussing the time in another country.


今、時間は日本で６時です。


This phrasing is rare but might be used by someone working across multiple time zones to specifically indicate JST. However, people usually say 日本の時間は6時です or 今は日本時間で6時です.
On the other hand, 日本に何時ですか is simply always incorrect.

Clear, thorough an straight to the point. I appreciate this answer a lot.
